# Connect mic to mixing software to reduce noise

Tags: microphone, jack, noise

I got a good usb microphone with excellent quality, but I also have a clicky mouse and keyboard (both with mechanical switches). I wanted to ask if it is possible to connect my mic to some kind of filter/sound editing software (via jack for example) where I can reduce the noise for calls via Skype and Hangouts?

Comment: You must provide details. What is the noise? Is it from Keyboard/Mouse etc. There are different solutions like hardware noise cancellation or by using a software.

Comment: My mic has unfortunately no noise canceling. Yes, my mouse and keyboard are loud